# Using foreign key to get all product from another table?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two table Order_table and Invoice_table ,i have order_id of Order_table which is foreign key of Invoice_table.
How to write the query in this situation in Laravel.

Comment: Hi Probir, we need the table definitions.

Comment: With your keyboard! Please provide a MVCE so we can help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for your comment,i have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather try to use eloquent relationship for this sort of problem. You can see here for the reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

As you said you should only include _"order_id"_ column in your *invoices* databse table.

In your *Order.php* model, write this code:

```
public function invoice()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice');
        }
```

In your *Invoice.php* model, write this code:

```
public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
```

and from the **Controller** you can use the eloquent query to get data. For example, you can get random 3 data using this code:

```
$results = Invoice::limit(3)->get();
      echo $results->order;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that the name of the models are `Invoice` and `Order`, you can use this code :

```
$invoice = Invoice::find($invoice_id);
$orders = $invoice->orders();
```